# Laravel - Set default value of column on record update

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this migration:

```php
class CreatePendingCredits extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('pending_credits', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->uuid('uuid')->unique()->default(DB::raw('UUID()'));
            $table->foreignIdFor(App\Models\User::class, 'user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->double('amount');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('pending_credits');
    }
}
```

When I'm creating a new record for `pending_credits`, I don't set `uuid` attribute, so database will generate a new uuid (uses the default value).

Let's say for some reason I need to update the uuid of one record just like when I'm creating a new record and database generates the uuid.

Is it:

```php
PendingCredit::find(18)->update(['uuid'=>null]);
```

Or:

```php
PendingCredit::find(18)->update(['uuid'=>DB::raw('UUID()')]);
```

Or is there a standard way to this?

---

#### Update

Imagine the default value is not just a simple `UUID()` in your database, then it's not good to copy your default expression from database into your code.

Comment: have you tried these to see?

Comment: I've tried `DB::raw...` but my question is, **"Is there any standard way to do this? Or we should do this by tricks?"** @lagbox

Comment: by what tricks? what is a trick to you? ... there is always the option of generating the UUID on the PHP side as well

Comment: In case of when the default value that is in your schema wasn't only a simple `UUID()` ! @lagbox

Comment: Honestly, I don't think there is a Laravel way to do this. Using `DB::raw('UUID()')` should be good because it will use the database UUID function and will leave the handling of UUIDs fully to the DB. That's what I would do.